# ServiceNow: Restrict visibility for Configuration Item for Inc, Prb and Chg

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, itil

As an ITIL user I should not see any Configuration Items prior to selecting Company

I know this is ready when:

Incident, Problem, Change:

- prior to selecting Company I don't see any Configuration Items when clicking Magnifying glass icon

Problem task/Change Task:

- I can see only Configuration Items within Comapny (from problem)

I tried to go to configuration dictionary for the configuration item to see if i can create a rule but that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Can you first please confirm that in the `task.cmdb_ci` dictionary record the **Dependent Field** is set to `company`?

If that is not your problem, then it may be that the dependent field is being ignored when the value is blank, or that it is matching on configuration items with a blank company. (Do you have any configuration items with a blank company?) In either case you would need to solve the problem using an Advanced Reference Qualifier.